# D3/Angular get window size

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I have a plunker here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-first-v-last-wide-labels?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts

I have a d3 chart in an Angular app.

I'm trying to capture the screen size and do something different when hovering over the bars below a screen size.

I'm trying to do this using

```
if (window.screen.width > 500) {
    alert('small')
}
```

This alerts all the time and not only when below 500

How can I capture screen size so I can use it in the code

Comment: Did you mean `window.screen.width < 500`?

Comment: It doesn't really matter I just need to be able to detect if the window is bigger or smaller than a certain size. I think I have it working now with `window.innerWidth < 600`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue,

this is how I fixed it

```
  public height = window.innerHeight;
  public width = window.innerWidth;
```

and in the ngOnInit you do your verification for the alert